# C# use generic invoke as MVC ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, generics

I have an Action in ASP.NET MVC4 that uses a generic method:

```
public ActionResult Test1()
{
    return Generic<TestClass>();
}

public ActionResult Test2(string className)
{
    MethodInfo method = typeof(ConfigController).GetMethod("Generic");
    MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(Type.GetType(className));
    generic.Invoke(this, null);
    return null; // Generic<TestClass>();
}

public ActionResult Generic<T>() where T : new()
{
    DatabaseUtil db = new DatabaseUtil();
    ViewBag.ClassName = typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName;
    return View("~/Views/Config/GenericConfig.cshtml", db.SelectAll<T>());
}
```

Test1() works just as expected, it passes along the `TestClass` to the generic method and returns the view using the model of appropriate objects.

I want to take this a step further and just pass the class name as a string so that I don't need a specific action for each type I want to use.

Test2() works up to the point where I return the view.  I know the `invoke` is working, as I hit a breakpoint in `Generic<T>` with the correct class type, but the return from Test2() is still what's passed back to the browser.

How can I delegate the return to the generically invoked `ActionResult` method?

Comment: I don't understand, why don't you simply return (ActionResult)generic.Invoke(null, null);? Side note: be incredibly careful with such code because it's possibly a big security hole (caller may instantiate any type (potentially also something performing an expensive or harmful operation in its constructor).

Comment: @Paul, why do you just pass in a code which could be the class name, then store a dictionary of codes to type, and instanciate it that way.  Then you will also remove the security flaw

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Still new to generics, I just found that solution myself right after making this post.

Comment: @johnny5 Good idea, I'll implement that for sure. It's an internal application, so security is not a huge concern, but always a good consideration.

Answer (score 3):

It was right in front of me (still new to reflection):

```
public ActionResult Test(string className)
{
    MethodInfo method = typeof(ConfigController).GetMethod("Generic");
    MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(Type.GetType(className));
    ActionResult ret = (ActionResult)generic.Invoke(this, null);
    return ret; 
}
```